# The definition of a metric and the triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\times X \to [0,\infty)$ and

1) $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$

2) $f(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$

(Note that we remove the triangle inequality from the definition of a metric.) My question is why the triangle inequality is necessary in the definition of a metric? Why it is useful?

Comment: In the definition of metric, one has that the space $X$ is not necessarily a topological space. In your definition $X$ must have a topology, otherwise "$f$ is continuous" does not make any sense. So metrics are useful to define topologies.

Comment: I guess you question is why do we include the triangle inequality in the definition of a metric? One answer is that you can imitate epsilon-delta proofs from real analysis very well once you have the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of a metric is supposed to capture the main features of the everyday idea of *distance between two points*. The most important parts of this idea are that

- a point is at zero distance from itself;
- distinct points are a positive distance apart;
- the distance from a point $x$ to a point $y$ is the same as the distance from $y$ to $x$; and
- the distance directly from a point $x$ to a point $y$ is never longer than the distance from $x$ to $y$ by way of some third point $z$.

The first two of these correspond to your $(2)$, and the third is your $(1)$; the fourth is the triangle inequality. Why pick these particular features? Basically because they turn out to be the most useful. They allow a great many arguments (e.g., $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs) from elementary analysis to be generalized to much more complicated and abstract settings.

It *is* possible to study functions that satisfy only some of these conditions. For instance, if we drop my second condition we get what are called [*pseudometrics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Pseudometrics), which turn out to be quite useful. What you’ve defined is called a [*semimetric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29#Semimetrics); people have studied them, but in general they aren’t very useful.

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out that the triangle inequality is what allows you to conclude that the topology generated by the open balls $B_x(\delta) := \{y\in X: d(x, y) < \delta\}$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @Andy: You also need both symmetry and the fact that a metric separates points in order to get that.